# How to prevent tkinter buttons from moving when label text length change?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-button

I have the following example:

```py
from tkinter import *
number = 0
​
window = Tk()
window.title("Program")
window.geometry('350x250')
​
label = Label(window, text=number)
label.grid(column=0,row=0)
​
def clicked_up():
    global number
    number += 1
    label.config(text=number)
​
def clicked_down():
    global number
    number -= 1
    label.config(text=number)
​
button1 = Button(window, text="Up", command=clicked_up)
button1.grid(column=1, row=1)
button2 = Button(window, text="Down", command=clicked_down)
button2.grid(column=2, row=1)
window.mainloop()
```

It increments the variable `number` (or decrements it) based on the button `Down` or `Up` presses.

The problem is, that the buttons are moving when the text in the Label (here it's the result of the increased/decreased variable) is changing length (eg: it's noticeable once it get bigger than 2 in length, so 10 or 100, or for negative, -100, is also noticeable)

I looked around but didn't think I found a solution, at least based on the above example.

Any way to do this?

Comment: `Label` should use `columnspan=3` to use 3 columns.

Comment: saw your last comment, found `width=` with `Label` and it seems to work, but probably need to make it auto resize to take into account the length of the number when it change length...Also tried `columnspan=3` and it seems to work fine, although would have preferred for the number to be close to the side/edge of the window (like when `columnspan=0`) @furas

Comment: you can add `sticky='w'` to keep it on `west` side of cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Label` can use `width=number_of_chars` to define place for new chars

```
label = Label(window, text=number, width=10)
```

Or

Label should use `columnspan=3` to use 3 columns in grid.

```
label.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=3)
```

Eventually it may need `sticky='w'` to align it to `west` side of cell

```
label.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=3, sticky='w')
```